# TS: how to transform Object.assign in ts file?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, ts-loader

I have some `Object.assign` usage in my ts files, and I am using `ts-loader` to handle ts files, however, I still find there are `Object.assign` in output js files. I have added `transform-object-assign` in my `.babelrc` file, and I find normal js files are all transformed, only ts files not. So is there any method to transform it in ts files ?

Answer (score 0):

> I find normal js files are all transformed, only ts files not.

Make sure the generate `.js` from TypeScript is being passed to Babel i.e. `ts-loader` then `babel-loader`

```
{
      test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: babelOptions
        },
      ]
    }
```

## More

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#babel

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign is ES6 feature

it should be done only with change ts target version in tsconfig

```
{    
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
    }
}
```